# Different ESP between terminal tabs or terminals

Tags: assembly, shellcode, aslr

I have seen that the address in the ESP register differs between the first and the second tab of the terminal. Also, the ESP sometimes changes after restarting the VM. The ASLR and the other protections are off. What happens here?

Comment: Stack contents may vary between executions, e.g. because of environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, the environment vars and args are at the top (highest addresses) of the stack on process entry.

`esp` on entry to `_start` points to `argc`, and right above that is `argv[]`.  (By value, not a pointer to argv.  CRT startup code has to `lea eax, [esp+4]` or something to get `&argv[0]`, and pass that to main.)

Above that is `envp[]`.  (I found a diagram in http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html.  See also [the i386 System V ABI documentation](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI).)

With ASLR disable, the highest address of the region mapped as stack memory is fixed, but a different sized environment will take up a different amount of space above the initial `esp`.